# Creating a shadow jar in gradle?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

```
tasks.register('uberJar', Jar) {
    archiveClassifier = 'Uber'

    manifest {
        attributes["Main-Class"] = mainClassName
    }

    from sourceSets.main.output

    dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.findAll { it.name.endsWith('jar') }.collect { zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working... I'm trying to make an uber jar with multiple dependencies, One-Jar seems to be outdated, and I can't use either the default gradle uberJar builder or shadow jar.

Comment: It is not a "shadow" JAR.  It is a "shaded" JAR.

Comment: Why can't you use the uberJar builder or the shadow plugin?  Try following the instructions here: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-fat-jar

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent the wheel and use [the plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow) for that. In the most simple scenario (which would probably work in your case), it's just a matter of:

```
plugins {
  id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '7.1.2'
}
```

And then:

```sh
./gradlew shadowJar
```

Comment: This works, unlike another one with the same name: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.xbib.gradle.plugin.shadow